# Count number of unique activities

Tags: r, dataframe, data-manipulation

I have a dataframe (simplified version) as follows:

```
df <- data.frame(ID = rep('A',7), Activity = 
 c('Login','Login','cat1','Login','cat2','Login','Login'))

  ID Activity
1  A    Login
2  A    Login
3  A     cat1
4  A    Login
5  A     cat2
6  A    Login
7  A    Login
```

Here is what I wish to do:

- start from the first row
- initiate `session=0`
- create a dataframe to hold `path` and `count`
- If the `Activity` is equal to `Login`, then `session=1`, check the next row's `Activity` and record it. This will be a `path` until the next `Login`
- continue until you hit the next `Login`, then set `session=2`.
- The final outcome for this example would be:

  ```
         Path          count
         Login           3
         Login, cat1     1
         Login, cat12    1
  ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create groups based on "Login", *split*, then *paste* per group, finally, aggregate using *table*:

```
data.frame(
  table(
    sapply(split(df$Activity, cumsum(df$Activity == "Login")), function(i){
      paste(i, collapse = ",")
    })))
#         Var1 Freq
# 1      Login    3
# 2 Login,cat1    1
# 3 Login,cat2    1
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
 group_by(grp = cumsum(Activity == "Login")) %>%
 summarise(Path = toString(Activity)) %>% 
 count(Path, name = "count")
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 3 × 2
  Path        count
  <chr>       <int>
1 Login           3
2 Login, cat1     1
3 Login, cat2     1
```